# Problem displaying the Facebook Request Dialog

Tags: facebook

The following code is supposed to display a Facebook Request Dialog:

```
<script>
  function sendFBRequest()
  {
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '111111111111111', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'apprequest', // this needs to be plural!
          message: 'Help me connect to Jane Doe',
          data: 'game47',
          title: 'Game Request'
          },
          function (response) 
          {
            if (response && response.request_ids) 
            {
                var requests = response.request_ids.join(',');
                alert('requests = ' + requests);
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert('canceled');
            }
          });
 }
 </script>

 <div class="awesome green" onClick="sendFBRequest();">Facebook Request</div>
```

When I click on the (awesome green) button, the basic dialog frame is displayed, and the dialog loading animation (flashing vertical grey bars) starts. But that's it, no message is ever displayed. What am I missing?

**Edit:**
I used the method 'apprequest' instead of **'apprequests'**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
FB.ui(
{method: 'apprequests',
message: 'my message',
data: 'some data',
title:'Mytitle'},
 function(response) {
 if (response) {

   window.location.reload();
 } else {

   window.location.reload();
 }
 }

 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.init({appId: '111111111111111', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
```

does not assume that user have logged in already.

Try make **FB.init** while page loading. And check FB api ready with **FB.getSession**[1] or better with **FB.getLoginStatus**[2]

[1] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getSession/

[2] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Humm, if I use the Send Dialog instead (method: send) then everything works as expected (but I don't get the response information). I'll check it out

Comment: response.status = 'connected'

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any javascript errors in your browser error console? There is a bug in how Facebook implemented things (in my opinion). If you have a Like button on the page, it calls an FB.init function which clobbers your initialization. You then get a javascript error that FB.init was not called when trying to call other Facebook functions.

I found I had to set the xfbml flag to false and use FB.XFBML.parse to render the parts of the page that had FBML. Which is more efficient anyway.